# Смена картинок по кнопкам на js

Tags: javascript

Задача - пять кнопок в ряд, при нажатии на каждую внизу по центру появляется своя картинка. Соответственно предыдущие картинки скрываются. Каждой кнопке соответствует своя картинка. Вот код:

```
<script>
    function vars() {
        let one=document.getElementById(imgOne);
        let two=document.getElementById(imgTwo);
        let three=document.getElementById(imgThree);
        let four=document.getElementById(imgFour);
        let five=document.getElementById(imgFive);
    }
    function show_hide1() {
        doc=document.getElementById(imgOne);
        if(doc.style.display == "none") doc.style.display = "block";
      five.style.display = "none";
      two.style.display = "none";
      three.style.display = "none";
      four.style.display = "none";
        else doc.style.display = "none";
      five.style.display = "none";
      two.style.display = "none";
      three.style.display = "none";
      four.style.display = "none";
    }
     function show_hide2() {
        doc=document.getElementById(imgTwo);
        if(doc.style.display == "none") doc.style.display = "block";
       five.style.display = "none";
       one.style.display = "none";
       three.style.display = "none";
       four.style.display = "none";
        else doc.style.display = "none";
       five.style.display = "none";
       one.style.display = "none";
       three.style.display = "none";
       four.style.display = "none";
    }
....
кнопки
 <div class="container">
    <input type="button" value="Поз" style="float: right" class="button" onclick="show_hide1();">
    <input type="button" value="драв" style="float: right" class="button" onclick="show_hide2();">
```

...
картинки

```
  <img src="unnamed.png" style="float: right; display: none" id="imgOne">
       <img src="img/firework.gif" style="float: right; display: none" id="imgTwo">
```

Не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка?

Comment: "в чем ошибка?" - в консоли браузера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//function vars() { <--
    let one = document.getElementById("imgOne");
    let two = document.getElementById("imgTwo");
    let three = document.getElementById("imgThree");
    let four = document.getElementById("imgFour");
    let five = document.getElementById("imgFive");
//} <--

function show_hide1() {
  if (one.style.display == "none")
    one.style.display = "block";
  else 
    one.style.display = "none";

  two.style.display = "none";
  three.style.display = "none";
  four.style.display = "none";
  five.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Написал все как в примере, все равно не работает :( 
В консоли выдает несколько однотипных ошибок типа: 
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at show_hide1 (index2.html:14)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index2.html:99)'

Comment: @Вадим Поместите скрипт внизу страницы.